# How to test chat application in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, chat, cucumber, integration-testing

What would be the best way to implement integration test for chat application?

The problem is that I don't know how to implement two user behavior without stubbing and mocking everything.

How would you implement these steps?

```
Given I have two users "joe" and "bob" logged in
When "joe" send "Hello!" message to "bob"
Then "bob" should see "Hello!"
```

What is the best way to test Ajaxy application with Cucumber?

How to test two users logged in at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to really test JS that way you are going to need to run these tests with a real browser process.

Have a look at http://seleniumhq.org/ and https://github.com/brynary/webrat/wiki/selenium

Answer (score 0):

[TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/) can also do JS web testing and can run multiple browsers at the same time. It's a bit of work but you can simulate a chat session between multiple users.